# Export an table from HTML to Excel via PHP

Tags: php

I have a PHP-code to export HTML to Excel. It is working fine but I want each table to be stored inside a new sheet. E.g. table1 in sheet1 and table2 in sheet2:

```
$file = "test.xls";
$table1 = "<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
$table2 = "<table><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $table1.$table2;
```

Comment: Create a proper excel document using [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize PHPExcel library for this:

```
$ews->setCellValue('a1', 'ID'); // Sets cell 'a1' to value 'ID 
$ews->setCellValue('b1', 'Season');
...
//Fill data 
$ews->fromArray($data, ' ', 'A2');
```

See [their site](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/)

Comment: is possible to store HTML table inside excel-sheet?